# Best way to Map data?

Tags: ruby

I wanna map some data from facebook into my User class. I read now some articles about inheritance, extending, including and so on. But maybe I understand something wrong. 
Is this the right approach for DataMapping in Ruby?

```
class User
    attr_accessible :name, :address

    def map_facebook
        FacebookUserMapper.new(facebook_object, self)
    end
end


class FacebookUserMapper

    def initialize(facebook_user, user)
        @facebook_user = facebook_user
        @user = user
        mapit
    end

    def self.map_it()
        username
        address
        return @user
    end

    def username
        @user.username = @facebook_user.name
    end

    def address
        @user.address = @facebook_user.address
    end     
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do like this:

```
def mapFacebook
  FacebookUserMapper.new(facebook_object, self).call
end

class FacebookUserMapper
  def initialize(facebook_user, user)
    @facebook_user = facebook_user
    @user = user
  end

  def call
    username
    address

    self
  end

  # ...
end
```

FYI: Don't add `()` around methods in Ruby

Answer (score 0):

The better way to map the facebook object on to your user model would be this

```
def self.from_omniauth(auth)
  where(auth.slice(:provider, :uid)).first_or_initialize.tap do |user|
    user.provider = auth.provider
    user.uid = auth.uid
    user.name = auth.info.name
    user.oauth_token = auth.credentials.token
    user.oauth_expires_at = Time.at(auth.credentials.expires_at)
    user.save!
  end
end
```

**auth** is the facebook object here. 
**tap** just allows you do do something with an object inside of a block, and always have that block return the object itself.

This is a code snippet from a [Railscasts episode](http://railscasts.com/episodes/360-facebook-authentication) from which you could get even more help for your facebook related app.

Comment: this was my first approach. CodeClimate says, that this is a long method, and I decided to refactor this method into small ones. also tests should be better to implement.

Comment: You are calling mapit (a class method) from the constructor through object. You should rather call as `self.class.mapit` And coming to testing part, you could also do test for the method i gave. This is not a long method, if remove `oauth related details` it would be less than 6 lines.  Not sure why CodeClimate refers a different long approach.